# find an item in an array to replace with null

Tags: java

Im using an array to hold property details stored alphabetically. I know I can't delete any from the array but i want to know how to find a specified property and then move all the other ones down an index and to replace the last one with null so that I don't have a duplicate at the end. My code never seems to come out of the loop.

```
public void removeProperty(String reference) {
    int index;
    Boolean found = false;
    for (index = 0; index < this.propertyList.length; index++) {
        if (this.propertyList[index].getReference().equalsIgnoreCase(reference)) {
            this.propertyList[index] = this.propertyList[index + 1];
            found = true;
        } else {
            index++;
        }

        if (found = true){
            while (index < this.propertyList.length) {
                this.propertyList[index] = this.propertyList[index + 1];
            }
            this.propertyList[this.propertyListSize - 1] = null;
            this.propertyListSize--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(found=true)` will always be true , you need `if(found == true)` which is same as `if(found)`

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use some `List` implementation (e.g. `ArrayList`) instead of an array. Lists provide methods to remove an element and make all following elements move up. The only difference would be that you won't have a `null` reference in the end of the list. But if for some reason you really need that, you could just add it manually.

Comment: You never modify `index` inside your `while` loop, so that's going to be an infinite loop. Looks like you also meant to have the `if (found == true)` outside the `for` loop.

Comment: another bug: the `index` is advanced both in the `for (...)` statement and in the `else` clause

Comment: instead of setting the boolean `found` and then asking about it , just imbed the code that deos the move inside the first `if`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that makes no use of boolean flag.  Other bugs that are resolved include:

1) increase of `index` inside `for` loop

2) `while` loop goes until last item. this will cause `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exceptuion. the loop should go until item before last.

```
public void removeProperty(String reference) {
    int index;
    // loop until reference found or end of array
    for (index = 0;
         index < this.propertyList.length &&
            this.propertyList[index].getReference().equalsIgnoreCase(reference) == false;
         index++);

    // if we didnt reach end of array - then we found refernce
    if (index < this.propertyList.length) {
        // loop until item before last
        while (index < this.propertyList.length-1) {
            this.propertyList[index] = this.propertyList[index + 1];
            index++;
        }
        // nullify last item
        this.propertyList[this.propertyList.length-1] = null;
        this.propertyListSize--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this doesn't answer most of your question but you can use apache commons ArrayUtils to remove an item from the array. [Here's](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html) the link.

Comment: Can you at least show the code required to solve this, assuming the library is loaded?